# App initializes twice. Is this typical behavior?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I'm currently testing a socket io app and I'm noticing unusual behavior. 
In my init python script I'm declaring a function that instantiates a flask object and initializes it via a socketIO instance (which is global) i.e. (assuming all of these files are within the same directory scope):

```
#/test_app/configs/__init__.py

__socketIO__ = SocketIO()
def create_app(address, port):
    app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    __socketIO__.init_app(app)

    return app
```

in another python script:

```
#/test_app/run_app.py

from configs import create_app
from configs import __socketIO__ as launch_socket

ip_address = '0, 0, 0, 0'
port = 5000

APP = create_app(ip_address, port)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'launching....'
    launch_socket.run(APP, debug=True, host=ip_addres, port=port)
```

Given this, if I run run_app.py, 'launching...' will print twice.
Is this behavior typical? Granted I'm still learning my way around socket.io so perhaps I'm missing some point to it. It just seems odd that it initializes twice. Is there a way to circumvent this behavior if it's unnecessary or detrimental?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal when you run in debug mode. Flask launches two processes, one for watching the code for changes and one for the actual flask process.

Comment: Agh. So obvious! Thanks!